# How to find the nth largest value of each row in SQL

Tags: sqlite

I have researched this problem and have found the answer for a single query, where you can find the nth value of a single column by using DESC OFFSET 2.  What I am trying to do is find the nth value for each item in a row.  For example, I'm working with a data base concerning bike share data.  The data base stores the duration of each trip and the date.  I'm trying to find the 3rd longest duration for each day in a data base.  If I was going to find the max duration I would use the following code.

```
SELECT DATE(start_date) trip_date, MAX(duration)
FROM trips
GROUP BY 1
```

I want the output to be something like this.

Date 3rd_duration

1/1/2017 334

1/2/2017 587

etc

If the value of the third longest duration is the same for two or more different trips, I would like the trip with the lowest trip_id to be ranked 3rd.

I'm working in SQLite. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You question is not clear  update your question add  a proper data sample and the expetced result

Comment: The answer to this question highly depends on the RDBMS you're using; can you confirm that you're looking for a solution either for MySQL or SQLite and that a solution for e.g. PostgreSQL is not relevant for you?

Comment: Also, as @scaisEdge mentioned: please provide sample data and expected output. Pay special attention to edge cases - what do you expect when there are less than 3 durations on a given day? What do you expect when all trips on a given day have equal length? What do you expect when the longest and second longest are obvious, but there are two trips with the same length behind them?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I upvoted it because the question is clear to me...but not the query :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This question shows research effort, is clear, and is useful? Really?

Comment: I gave you a solution below which should run in SQLite.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried this but it crashed I think.  There are 313689 trips in the data base over the course of three years.  I ran the query for 20 minutes locally on a macbook.

Answer (score 0):

Neither SQLite nor MySQL have a `ROW_NUMBER` function built in, so get ready for an ugly query.  We can still group by the date, but to find the max duration we can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    DATE(t1.start_date) AS start_date,
    t1.duration
FROM trips t1
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trips t2
     WHERE DATE(t2.start_date) = DATE(t1.start_date) AND
           t2.duration <= t1.duration) = 3;
```

Note that this approach might break down if you could have, for a given date, more than one record with the same duration.  In this case, you might get multiple results, neither of which might actually be the third highest duration.  In order to handle such ties, you should tell us what the logic is with regard to ties.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester